# fancybox3 multiple instances

Tags: jquery, fancybox, multiple-instances

I need help with fancybox v3 and multiple instances.  I have an AJAX call and if the call is successful then I need to show two fancyboxes with information.  Now I am able to show to fancyboxes but after closing it creates a new same visible DIV. Do you understand? I am including screenshots of the problem. Thank you

After closing fancyboxes:
[image: After closing fancyboxes]

HTML before fancyboxes:
[image: HTML before fancyboxes]

HTML before fancyboxes:
[image: HTML after closing fancyboxes]

My code is: #notification, #popup-related are defined in html. After load I must to add class opened (display: block !important). Without this it does not show div #popuprelated.  I tried add removeclass, etc. in afterclose but without success.

```
   $('#notification').html('<div class="popup- 
   container">tetetetetetete</div>');

      var html = '';
      var data = json['products_related'];
      html += '<div class="popup>sdfdsfdsfsdfds</div>'

  $('#popup-related').html(html);

  $.fancybox.open({
    src  : '#notification, #popup-related',
    closeExisting: false,
    scrolling: 'no',
    iframe : {
      scrolling : 'no'
    },
    afterLoad: function () {
        $("#popup-related").addClass('opened');
    },
    afterClose: function () {

    },
  });
```

Comment: Your HTML should be pasted as text here, not images.  See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question

Comment: Since you are having problems to find answers, I suggest you edit your question. Focus to provide a good problem description. For guidance please read [how to ask questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to create a minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)